# Is it possible to reduce repetitive permutation-based if-statements?

Tags: c#, math, optimization, permutation, dry

Hello I'm working on this math game and for my last scene I did what feels like a lot of repetitive code but I'm not sure if there's a way to simplify it, I have linked below so maybe some more seasoned programmers might have some more elegant solutions!
For example, Im trying to generate every permutation of something like (a[]b)²[]c[]d where the brackets will be replaced by +,-,*, or /. What I have been doing is just creating random percent if statements to pick a specific version like "(a+b)²/c-d" Is there possibly a less "brute-force" and readable approach then what I have been doing?

```
if(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101)>50){
        // 50% of being (a+b)²(c)+d
    if(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101)>50){
        ans = ((int) Mathf.Pow((float) a+ (float) b, 2))*c+d;
        input.text = "("+a+"+"+b+")"+"²"+"("+c+")"+"+"+d+"=";
        Debug.Log("Problem ID: 78");
        // 50% of being (a+b)²(c)-d
    } else {
        ans = ((int) Mathf.Pow((float) a+ (float) b, 2))*c-d;
        input.text = "("+a+"+"+b+")"+"²"+"("+c+")"+"-"+d+"=";
        Debug.Log("Problem ID: 79");
    }
    // 50% of being (a-b)²(c)[]d
} else {
    // 50% of being (a-b)²(c)+d
    if(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101)>50){
        ans = ((int) Mathf.Pow((float) a- (float) b, 2))*c+d;
        input.text = "("+a+"-"+b+")"+"²"+"("+c+")"+"+"+d+"=";
        Debug.Log("Problem ID: 80");
        // 50% of being (a-b)²(c)-d
    } else {
        ans = ((int) Mathf.Pow((float) a- (float) b, 2))*c-d;
        input.text = "("+a+"-"+b+")"+"²"+"("+c+")"+"-"+d+"=";
        Debug.Log("Problem ID: 81");
    }
```

(Pastebin below for more context)
https://pastebin.pl/view/d1bfb99e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I applaud your desire to make your code more readable. The basic idea is to split (a) defining, (b) choosing and (c) applying your operators.

- Step 1: You define `Operator`s. Each `Operator` combines both a mathematical operation (e.g. `Add` would be `(a, b) => a + b`) and a symbol (e.g. `Add` would be `"+"`).

  ```
  class Operator
  {
      public Func<int, int, int> Calculate { get; }
      public string Symbol { get; }

      public Operator(Func<int, int, int> calculate, string symbol)
      {
          Calculate = calculate;
          Symbol = symbol;
      }
  }

  private Operator Add = new Operator((a, b) => (a + b), "+");
  private Operator Subtract = new Operator((a, b) => (a - b), "-");
  ```
- Step 2: Then you randomly choose your operators (I used `System.Random`, since I'm not familiar with Unity, but feel free to replace it with the random number generator of your choice):

  ```
  var rnd = new Random();

  private (Operator op1, Operator op2, int problemId) RandomlyChooseProblem()
  {
      switch (rnd.Next(4))
      {
          case 0: return (Add, Add, 78);
          case 1: return (Add, Subtract, 79);
          case 2: return (Subtract, Add, 80);
          case 3: return (Subtract, Subtract, 81);
          default: throw new InvalidOperationException("This should not happen.");
      }
  }
  ```
- Step 3: You apply them:

  ```
  var (op1, op2, problemId) = RandomlyChooseProblem();

  ans = op2.Calculate((int)Math.Pow(op1.Calculate(a, b), 2) * c, d);
  input.text = $"(a{op1.Symbol}b)²*c{op2.Symbol}d");
  Debug.Log($"Problem ID: {problemId}");
  ```

Adding a new operator (e.g. `Multiply`) or a new problem variant (e.g. `(Add, Multiply, 82)`) is now just a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Break the calculation into parts - `a±b`, `square * c` and `±d`. Calculate them separately, and multiply them to get the final result. For the text, you can use string interpolation

```
float ans;
string operator1;
string operator2;
if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101)>50) {
    ans = (float) a + (float) b;
    operator1 = "+";
} else {
    ans = (float) a - (float) b;
    operator1 = "-";
}
ans = (int)(ans * ans) * c;
if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101)>50) {
    ans += d;
    operator2 = "+";
} else {
    ans -= d;
    operator2 = "-";
}
input.text = $"(a{operator1}b)²(c){operator2}d";
```

Also note that `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,101) > 50` is not exactly 50% probability. You probably meant `UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,101) > 50` instead, but I would just use `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,2) == 0`.

The problem IDs can be flattened by generating 2 random bits, and adding the 2-bit number encoded by those bits to 78:

```
float ans;
string operator1;
string operator2;
int random1 = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,2);
int random2 = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,2);
if (random1 == 0) {
    ans = (float) a + (float) b;
    operator1 = "+";
} else {
    ans = (float) a - (float) b;
    operator1 = "-";
}
ans = (int)(ans * ans) * c;
if (random2 == 0) {
    ans += d;
    operator2 = "+";
} else {
    ans -= d;
    operator2 = "-";
}
int problemID = 78 + random1 + random2 * 2;
Debug.Log($"Problem ID: {problemID}");
input.text = $"(a{operator1}b)²(c){operator2}d";
```

This trick is not particularly readable IMO though.

Comment: So what it sounds like if I want to simplify it I should use a model like (a[]b)²[]c[]d and then for this section of code generate a[+,-,*,/]b and do that for each variable interaction. And possible abstract-ify it into. A switch case method so I can repeat it for something when I do something like a[]b[]c[]d or a[]b[](c[]d)

Comment: @BriceBrown If you have that many operators, you should probably try Heinzi's answer instead.